# MVC Web API Call From Android Application

Tags: android, sql, eclipse, api, model-view-controller

I have an MVC Web API application running in VS 2012. It is connected to a SQL Server Database with some data. I want to output this data to a textview on my android application but I cannot find any good tutorials that does exactly that. If you could guide me in the direction of one that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Android app will need to use HTTP to get the data from your Web API.  This will most likely be JSON that it retrieves, processes, and then updates the TextView.

This tutorial will show you what to do: http://blog.strikeiron.com/bid/73189/Integrate-a-REST-API-into-Android-Application-in-less-than-15-minutes